# Canvas - LMS - How to get answers submitted by a user for a quiz?

Tags: rest, api, http, documentation, canvas-lms

I am trying to get the answers submitted by a user for a certain question of a certain quiz.

I tried the following API endpoints, but none of them are returning the desired data:

1. GET https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/:course_id/quizzes/:quiz_id/questions
2. GET https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/:course_id/quizzes/:quiz_id/questions?quiz_submission_id=:quiz_submission_id&quiz_submission_attempt=1
3. GET https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/:course_id/quizzes/:quiz_id/submissions/:id

Following is the documentation that I've tried to search:

1. https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quiz_submissions.html#method.quizzes/quiz_submissions_api.show

Comment: Please include an example of what you are expecting and what it's returning.